# I am trying to build an app and cannot reach my localhost:5060 server while serving my files using node.js through wsl. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I have been trying to connect to localhost to run an extremely rudimentary web app. I have wsl2 (which I began using for comp sci classes) on my Windows 10 machine, and because I've used it so much and now gotten used to it, I wanted to run node.js through wsl2 (my distribution is Ubuntu 22.04.1 lts). When I run the "node server.js" command in my VScode terminal, VScode says that my application open on port 5060 is available, but when I click "open in browser," chrome gives me this: "The webpage at http://localhost:5060/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." I have the live server extension enabled in my Windows VScode environment and have used it before, but ideally, I would like to stay in wsl using node.js so I can learn it.

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express")();
const path = require("path");

const app = express;

app.get("/*", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("frontend", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5060, () => console.log("server running..."));
```

I began by googling, and the main fixes were toggling the firewall and clearing DNS cache. I toggled my windows firewall on and off to no avail, and did the same with ufw in ubuntu, which did not solve annything. I cleared DNS cache in windows. When troubleshooting on the linux side, I found out that systemd is important and that my wsl2 does not have it, so I could not clear DNS. I installed apache in wsl as well, but that didn't seem to do anything either. I have not messed with changing apache from localhost:80 to 8080 (I could not find the file path and I have no idea if I am supposed to change it in windows or wsl or if I even have it in windows).

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>da first</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class = "nav">
        <a href = "/" class = "nav__link" data-link>Dashboard</a><!--navigational tag-->
        <a href = "/posts" class = "nav__link" data-link>Posts</a><!-- "data-link" allows for movement between pages without refresh?
        possible links to history api in javascript? -->
        <a href = "/settings" class = "nav__link" data-link>Settings</a>
    </nav>
    <script type = "module" src = "/static/js/index.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm extremely new and have zero formal training in javascript or node, so my lack of fundamentals could be stopping me from seeing an obvious problem, so please help!